# Setting calendar and adding 1 day

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have a string (e.g. Oct 15 Wednesday), then I have to get the next day of this day. I have a method that I use to do this, but after the present month, it throws wrong date. Here's the method:

```
public String getNextDay(String lastDate) {
    String[] wholedate = lastDate.split("\\s+");
    String datemon = wholedate[0];
    String date = wholedate[1];
    String dateday = wholedate[2];

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd cccc");

    int dayNo=0;
    if (dateday.equalsIgnoreCase("Sunday")) {
        dayNo = Calendar.SUNDAY;
    } else if (dateday.equalsIgnoreCase("Monday")) {
        dayNo = Calendar.MONDAY;
    } else if (dateday.equalsIgnoreCase("Tuesday")) {
        dayNo = Calendar.TUESDAY;
    } else if (dateday.equalsIgnoreCase("Wednesday")) {
        dayNo = Calendar.WEDNESDAY;
    } else if (dateday.equalsIgnoreCase("Thursday")) {
        dayNo = Calendar.THURSDAY;
    } else if (dateday.equalsIgnoreCase("Friday")) {
        dayNo = Calendar.FRIDAY;
    } else if (dateday.equalsIgnoreCase("Saturday")) {
        dayNo = Calendar.SATURDAY;
    }

    int monNo = 0;
    if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Jan")) {
        monNo = Calendar.JANUARY;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Feb")) {
        monNo = Calendar.FEBRUARY;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Mar")) {
        monNo = Calendar.MARCH;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Apr")) {
        monNo = Calendar.APRIL;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("May")) {
        monNo = Calendar.MAY;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Jun")) {
        monNo = Calendar.JUNE;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Jul")) {
        monNo = Calendar.JULY;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Aug")) {
        monNo = Calendar.AUGUST;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Sep")) {
        monNo = Calendar.SEPTEMBER;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Oct")) {
        monNo = Calendar.OCTOBER;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Nov")) {
        monNo = Calendar.NOVEMBER;
    } else if (datemon.equalsIgnoreCase("Dec")) {
        monNo =Calendar.DECEMBER;
    }

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(date));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monNo);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayNo);

    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    String fd = df.format(cal.getTime());

    return fd;
}
```

Maybe I set the date wrong or maybe I need to set more for the date, or maybe there is a better way to do this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you , I would do like this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); 

String nextDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Whut? I need the date format to be "MMM dd cccc" and I have data to set as the date.

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution is to call Calendar.getTimeInMillis() to get the UTC time stamp, add 24x60x60x1000 milliseconds to it, and then put it into another Calendar.

No other extra step needed for this approach. It should be error-free, though the efficiency could be a little bit poor. However, I take simplicity as the first priority.

Comment: If the date you are adding the day to happens to be a daylight saving change day, then this approach can fail. I have seen examples of it failing for late March and late October in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

I finally know how to do this, to not set day of week. For some reason, it messes the date up. So now, i just set the day_of_month and month, and i works fine. thank you guys.